# Getting webservice methods from Soap Client using reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, reflection

I'm trying to get a MethodInfo collection from a SOAPClient object that contains only the methods of the webservice itself. Here is what I'm currently doing. At the moment it returns all the methods of the MyServiceSoapClient.

```
MyServiceSoapClient myService = new MyServiceSoapClient();
MethodInfo[] methods = myService.GetType().GetMethods();
```

Answer (score 2):

The GetMethods() method supports bindingflags that you can use to more specifically select the methods you want it to return. Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx

Also, you could use some linq to further specify what you are after:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = myService.GetType().GetMethods();
MethodInfo[] methodsOfWebservice = methods.Where(m => m.whatever == whatever && m.anothercondition == true); // etc.
```

The last option you have is to add an Attribute to every method you want it to return and then test for the presence of the Attribute. Have a look here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/attributes.aspx

**Update 2011-01-18**

I've looked at Microsoft KnowledgeBase and found that the [WebMethod] is an attribute.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28a537td.aspx.
When getting all methods you could test for the presence of this attribute to decide whether the method is a WebMethod or not.

```
List<MethodInfo> methodsOfWebservice = new List<MethodInfo>();
MethodInfo[] methods = myService.GetType().GetMethods();
foreach(MethodInfo method in methods)
{
  foreach (Attribute attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes(true))
  {
    if (attribute is WebMethodAttribute)
      methodsOfWebservice.Add(method);
  }
}
```

**Update 2011-01-20**

I just tested the following code and it does in fact give me the the `WebMethodAttribute` in the `attribute` variable:

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
var method = type.GetMethod("methodname");
var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebMethodAttribute), true);
```

I'm sure you should be able to do the same with your code and test for the presence of the WebMethodAttribute

Comment: I don't really want to add attributes to the methods myself. Do you know of a way to identify the methods as belonging to the websevice. The linq query is fine but doesn't really answer the question. What I'm looking for is the property to replace m.whatever with.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know which specific methods you would like to have returned and which not. I can give a code example using LINQ that is more specific if you provide me with your source code. Can you add the code of your `MyServiceSoapClient` class, and indicate which methods you would like to have returned?

Comment: The methods I want returned are the web service methods that is the methods marked as [WebMethod] in the asmx file. I want to exclude methods which come from the SOAP client such as get_ClientFactory.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer. The code isn't completely perfect as it doesn't do any error handling, and I haven't tested this code but it should serve to give you an idea. Have a browse through the Codeproject.com link in my answer on Attributes as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think we are on the right lines. The problem is that the GetCustomAttributes method is returning an empty array. This is probably because the WebMethod attribute is set in the asmx file. The object that we are interrogating is constructed by visual studio when the service reference is added and is not the class where the WebMethod attribute is declared.

Comment: That could be true, I'm not sure about the asmx file, but doesn't reflection take effect AFTER all partials have been compiled into one class?? Please have a look at my update of today. I've been trying a few things around the `WebMethodAttribute` and can indeed detect it's presence with reflection and `GetCustomAttributes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method with XML parsing:

First I download the XML from the WSDL:

```
private string GetPageSource(string url)
    {
        string htmlSource = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("ProxyAdress", 8080);
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = myProxy;
                client.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
                htmlSource = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // log any exceptions
        }
        return htmlSource;
    }
```

Then I am parsing the XML to the node where the methods for the SOAP-Client are and adding them to a generic list of strings:

```
_strXmlFromUrl = GetPageSource(_strWebserviceUrl); // My TestUrl: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nmspManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nmspManager.AddNamespace("wsdl", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/");
xmlDoc.LoadXml(_strXmlFromUrl);
XmlNodeList methodNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation[@name]", nmspManager);
List<string> lstMehtodNames = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < methodNodes.Count; i++)
{
    lstMehtodNames.Add(String.Concat(methodNodes[i].ParentNode.Attributes["name"].Value,": " ,methodNodes[i].Attributes[0].Value));
}
```

Have fun with it.

Taragneti