# Can you detect web service parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I will try to explain this the best I can. I want to detect how many parameters a web service needs and the type of parameter e.g. string, using C#. I'm not sure if this is actually possible.

The reason for this is that I want to dynamically populate a form with the relevant input fields. For example if a web service had a string parameter I would populate the form with a textbox.

Any suggestions if this is actually possible, or any suggestions on any other ways to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about complex types? What if an object is required to be passed in as a parameter?

Comment: The following post may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13987114/1600654

Comment: Do you have access to the webservice source code ? Is it yours ?

Comment: Never any objects to be passed, only barcodes, item nos etc. Yes they are my webservices. My reason for doing this is that the software will be on handheld devices and if I can populate the forms via the web service requirements it will stop me having to deploy to 100+ handhelds everytime we update.