# Call SOAP web service on winform and get available methods in the SOAP service

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrrKt.png)

I am trying to build something like this, where user will put the URL of the web service and the available methods will be listed below in the combo-box.

Comment: Add "?wsdl" to the end of the url and parse the information you are interested in from the WSDL that returns.

Comment: You might save yourself some work if [wcftestclient.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe) is an option.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715456/getting-webservice-methods-from-soap-client-using-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715456/getting-webservice-methods-from-soap-client-using-reflection)

Comment: but how to use SOAP url without using service reference

Comment: SOAP is just a POST of xml. If you can properly craft the (likely complex) XML don't need a service reference but there is a reason it is so common to generate service reference.